# Android iterate through TableLayout, disable all Buttons

Tags: android

I have created a poor-man's keyboards out of buttons, and I've placed them in a TableLayout using three rows like so:

> ```
> <TableLayout
> android:id="@+id/TableLayout_Keyboard"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:layout_weight="1">
>
> <TableRow
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_Q"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/q"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_W"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/w"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_E"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/e"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_R"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/r"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_T"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/t"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_Y"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/y"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_U"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/u"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_I"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/i"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_O"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/o"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_P"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/p"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
> </TableRow>
>
> <TableRow
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_A"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/a"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_S"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/s"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_D"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/d"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_F"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/f"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_G"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/g"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_H"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/h"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_J"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/j"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_K"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/k"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_L"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/l"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
> </TableRow>
>
> <TableRow
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_Z"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/z"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_X"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/x"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_C"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/c"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_V"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/v"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_B"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/b"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_N"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/n"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/Keyboard_Btn_M"
>         android:layout_width="35dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:onClick="keyboardButtonPressed"
>         android:text="@string/m"
>         android:textSize="14sp"
>         tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
> </TableRow>
> ```

Now I want to make a method which programmatically disables all the buttons. I tried doing this:

```
private void disableKeyboard(){
    TableLayout keyboard = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout_Keyboard);

    for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = keyboard.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof Button) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I thought `.getChildAt()` would get the TableRows, so I did this:

```
private void disableKeyboard(){
    TableLayout keyboard = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout_Keyboard);

    for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = keyboard.getChildAt(i);

        if(v instanceof TableRow) {
            for(int j=0; j < ((TableRow) v).getChildCount(); j++){
                View vv = keyboard.getChildAt(i);

                if (vv instanceof Button) {
                    vv.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that didn't work either. How can I loop through all the buttons and disable them?

EDIT found the solution:

```
private void disableKeyboard(){
    TableLayout keyboard = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout_Keyboard);
    ArrayList<View> layoutButtons = keyboard.getTouchables();

    for(View v : layoutButtons){
        if( v instanceof Button ) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulation! Now you can move the solution as answer then mark it as an accepted answer. Please don't include your solution in the answer. So you can help other who will facing the same problem in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that disabling the buttons makes them "untouchable" - meaning I can't get them with `.getTouchables()` after they have been disabled. I wanted to create a toggle function (so that I could toggle between enabled/disabled), and had to do this:

```
private ArrayList<View> keyboardButtons;

private void storeKeyboardButtons(){
    TableLayout keyboard = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout_Keyboard);
    ArrayList<View> layoutButtons = keyboard.getTouchables();

    for(View v : layoutButtons){
        if( v instanceof Button ) {
            keyboardButtons.add(v);
        }
    }
}

private void toggleKeyboard(boolean whichState){
    //whichState == true enables ALL the buttons
    //whichState == false disables ALL the buttons

    for (View v: keyboardButtons) {
        v.setEnabled(whichState);
    }
}
```

I first store all the buttons in the keyboard in a variable called "keyboardButtons", this method (storeKeyboardButtons) is called from the onCreate -method. Later when I want to enable or disable the buttons I simply call the toggleKeyboard -method and pass true for enable, and false for disable.